# Html video shows white screen when added dynamically using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, video

Using jQuery, I'm sending an AJAX request that will send back JSON data with HTML code. The html code will then be appended to the document's body. Here is what I'm doing:

```
$.get('get.php', { req: 'video_html' }, function (data) {

    if (data.responsetype === "SUCCESS") {

        $(document.body).append(data.video_html);
    }
});
```

The video_html code is as following:

```
<video id="newVideo" src="http://.... .mp4" preload="yes">
    Your browser does not support video playing.
</video>
```

The video is added to the document body successfully, the URL (src attribute) is also linked properly to the video but it shows a white screen instead. Anyone knows why?

Comment: I feel problem with `append`. Try once with `html`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Still the same. It's not working.

Comment: Are you sure the video URL is correct? Is the video encoded in a manner that works in browsers?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's all correct. I finally found a solution. I've posted an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a timeout and it worked:

```
$.get('get.php', { req: 'video_html' }, function (data) {

    setTimeout(function(){

        if (data.responsetype === "SUCCESS") {

            $(document.body).append(data.video_html);
        }

    }, 1000);
});
```